# power supply input : AC 13V output : DC 5v, DC 9v,AC 8v

Tags: power-supply, power

i am alredy to develop a schematic of power supply with Trasnfo 13V , 1,5A : 
[image]

so this my schematic and i want to voltage in U2 be continue and i need a solution

and i am chagin now the schematic by new and i have this result :

[image]

Comment: You should connect your regulator GND points to ground. And your 7809 circuit is just wrong. The regulator GND terminal is labelled that for a reason.

Comment: i am doing a new schematic and the voltage of U2 is not stable .. i need to be stable like U1

Comment: Try connecting the rectifier in bridge configuration (GND connected to left terminal instead of bottom terminal.)

Comment: On the 7805, the GND terminal is floating. Tie it to ground.

Comment: The 7809 requires that its input voltage is at least 11 volts (at least 2 volts above the output) in order for it maintain a 9 volt output.  Check the input voltage to the 7809 - you may need to increase the value of C1 to keep the voltage high enough for U2 to regulate.

Answer (score 1):

@ Peter Bennett 
 i increase tha value of the capacitor in C1 i put another Capation with the same value 1000 uf , the voltage in the 7809 is stable . 
[image]

thank you